# Google Cloud Functions Execution Time & Limitations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a very simple pixel-server that retrieves client request header/params/body to publish messages to a pub/sub topic & it's written in cloud function. In an ideal scenario, the function will not take more than 5-10ms to execute, in best case less than 5ms.

[image]

But then, in the logs, I am seeing some function invocations are taking >500ms

[image]

I am trying to understand the behaviour of cloud function cold-start & auto-scaling to co-relate with cost as we will end up paying 50% more if 10% of the invocation runs 100x slower due to the cold start/autoscaling

[image]

Could someone from the community point out the best practices to overcome this scenario to save cost & improve performance due to cold-start as we need to deal more than 100M request? Also, due to our amount of invocations (100M+) does cloud function / pub-sub comes with any invocation/scale-up limitations we need to start considering or think of a non-serverless solution (**wink**)?

Comment: I find your question interesting but is short on details to get a real answer. First, you have not shown any code, which means that we can only guess or provide general information which you can simply find using a Google search. Without details on your code, libraries, etc. we can only guess on cold start issues.

Comment: Next, you are not showing any graphs that show traffic over time. Is your typical traffic bursty or smooth? Your service may be better suited for App Engine or Cloud Run, but I don't know as your question does not provide details necessary to answer with facts as opposed to generalizations. Cloud Functions is a great platform, but it is not the "end-all" solution in every case.

Comment: Third, your comment about cost increases due to cold starts and autoscaling is not correct. Where did you get information that you pay for cold starts or autoscaling? If pricing and cold starts are an issue, you may want to use Google Compute Engine which is cheaper at your invocation numbers.

Comment: First - Thanks for your feedback & comments. I am just doing some initial evaluation on cloud functions & it's features to do some realtime tracking through GTM to push its limitations. Then I am stuck with evaluating the cost before making it live, if you think a better way to evaluate the cost of cloud function could you provide to any links from google? When I tried to do some basic performance testing (with 1000s of call) - we ended up seeing our 30% of calls are going beyond 300-500ms rest of the calls are less than 10ms.

Comment: I am just thinking to release in an incremental way - lets say based on traffic expectations for certain pages/app screens, limiting the events/pages captured (using GTM) and calling the cloud function endpoint with the respective params

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several tips from the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#performance) that may help you reduce the performance issues:

- **Remove unused dependencies**

  > If your functions import modules, the load time for those modules can add to the invocation latency during a cold start. You can reduce this latency, as well as the time needed to deploy your function, by loading dependencies correctly and not loading dependencies your function doesn't use.
- **Use global variables to reuse objects in future invocations**

  > There is no guarantee that the state of a Cloud Function will be preserved for future invocations. However, Cloud Functions often recycles the execution environment of a previous invocation. If you declare a variable in global scope, its value can be reused in subsequent invocations without having to be recomputed.
- **Do lazy initialization of global variables**

  > If you initialize variables in global scope, the initialization code will always be executed via a cold start invocation, increasing your function's latency. If some objects are not used in all code paths, consider initializing them lazily on demand.

Also regarding the access to Google APIs, as you are fetching messages from PUB/SUB, it's better to create the Pub/Sub client object in global scope. There's more information and a sample code regarding that in the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking#accessing_google_apis).

Cloud Functions also need some time to scale-up, therefore if the amount of requests is too high, this may also be causing the high latency you've been experiencing. One workaround could be creating two Cloud Functions subscribed to your Pub/Sub topic, or even have 2 separated topics for the 2 functions and then you will split the workload within these two.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - let me try your recommendations this week & see if I have any improvements :-)

Comment: @Logan any update on this? Were you successful in decreasing the function execution time?